# POST запрос у  checkbox

Tags: php

Как получить значение через POST у флажков???

Например

```
     <input type="checkbox" name="Антон" value="a1" checked>Антон<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Максим" value="a2"> Максим<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Игорь" value="a3"> Игорь<br> 
     <input type="checkbox" name="Аркадий" value="a4"> Аркадий<br> 
     <input type="submit" value="Выбрать"></p>
```

Ну и как достать значение надо к каждому варианту прописывать  вот так

```
        $name = $_POST['Антон'];
         $name = $_POST['Максим'];
        $name = $_POST['Игорь'];
```

И что будет зранится в $name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю флажком вы назвали checkbox.

Получение значения - так-же как и у любого другого поля, ничем не отличается.

P.S. Надо разные имена у checkbox делать

UPD:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Антон" checked>Антон<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Максим"> Максим<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Игорь"> Игорь<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Аркадий"> Аркадий<br>
```

Вот что получите:

```
print_r( $_POST['name'] );
```

Конкретная реализация зависит от того - что вам нужно...

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно выбрать несколько флажков нужно еще в name="" заносить массивом.
Например name="country" надо так name="country[]".

Еще можно так:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Антон">Антон<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Максим"> Максим<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Игорь"> Игорь<br> 
     <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="Аркадий"> Аркадий<br> 
     <input type="submit" value="Выбрать">

$joined_name = join(", ", $_POST['name']);
echo "$joined_name";
```

В этом случае имена выведутся через запятую.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/55370/